# Chart JS 2 Tick Label Border

Tags: html5-canvas, chart.js

I am using Chart JS 2.6.0. I am using a blue background for the chart with labels in white colour. However, when chart gets rendered on the screen, there is a black border across the labels, as shown here:

[image: https://pasteboard.co/1LdsD37jh.png]

Is there a way to get rid of this border or if I can style the border itself and make it transparent or white somehow?

Update:

Adding the code for reference. I am setting font color and size within 'ticks' object of xAxes and yAxes:

```
const TYPE = 'horizontalBar';

        let data = {
            labels: ['National', 'Banner Groups'],
            datasets: [{
                backgroundColor: '#fff',
                data: [10, 20]
            }]
        };

        let options = {
            showDatapoints: true,
            scales: {

                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                responsive: true,
                xAxes: [{

                    ticks: {
                        fontColor: '#fff',
            fontSize: 15,
                        beginAtZero: true

                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        fontColor: '#fff',
                        fontSize: 15,
                        fontStyle: 'bold'
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false
                    }
                }]
            },

            legend: {
                display: false
            }
        };


        let cf: any = {
            type: TYPE,
            data: data,
            options: options
        };
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j6nqt4oo/ If the chart is resized and made bigger, there is no issue. However, if we shrink the size, the issue pops up.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the jsfiddle in the 2nd comment to the original question.  I do not see the black border at any browser window size.  Is this perhaps browser specific?  Or maybe even the fonts available?

The environments I tried:

- Windows 10 Home

  - Firefox 54.0 (32-bit)
  - Edge
  - IE 11
  - Google Chrome
- Fedora 24 4.11.6-101.fc24.x86_64

  - Firefox 54.0 (64-bit)
  - Google Chrome 59.0 (64-bit)
- Android (Samsung Galaxy Prime)

  - Google Chrome

It looked correct in all of those, at all screen sizes.